# How can I keep lines with missing columns upon importing CSV to BigQuery?

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

I have a HUGE csv database (46 million lines) that I'm trying to upload to BQ to work with. The problem is the last column is not filled on about half the lines. So, I get this error:

```
Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 40, but line starting at position:X contains only 40 columns
```

I have already set every column as "nullable". I have allowed for maximum 100 million errors. What happens is BQ skips the lines with a null last column - all 20M+ of them.

What should I do? Manually get rid of the final value, since it's a boolean that I won't use for analysis? Or is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Load the file in a single column as it it was a single entry for a cell by using a separator that doesn't exists in the file. Then work out a SQL solution or a UDF to parse that single column into it's specific cells. You could also export the single column by adding the missing cell if you know what CSV sytnax sugar to add to correct your file, and then import back again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution @Pentium10 suggests in the comments is very interesting and should work.

You can also load your file with the `bq load` command, and set the `--allow_jagged_row` to `true`. It gives flexibility on the missing trailing columns.

`bq` reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_load)