# BigQuery CSV Upload - Failed to Create Table

Tags: csv, ms-access, google-bigquery, position

I'm new to BigQuery and trying to upload a CSV.  I keep getting various versions of this error:  Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 23, but line starting at position:9602564 contains only 7 columns.

Any ideas what is wrong with my CSV?  I'm pulling it out of MS Access, I've tried both exporting as Excel and as .txt and then converting to CSV and I get the same error every way I've tried.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101585/how-can-i-keep-lines-with-missing-columns-upon-importing-csv-to-bigquery    ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I keep lines with missing columns upon importing CSV to BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68101585/how-can-i-keep-lines-with-missing-columns-upon-importing-csv-to-bigquery)